# rails form helper password security issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is the font-code.

```
<%= form_for(:something, :html=> {:id => 'login'}, :url => 'login/create') do |form| %>
        <h1>Log In</h1>
        <fieldset id="inputs">
            <%= form.text_field :username, :placeholder => 'Username', :autofocus=>true%>

            <%= password_field_tag(:password, :placeholder => 'Password') %>
            <%= password_field_tag :userpass1, placeholder: 'Password'%>
            <%= password_field_tag :userpass, params[:userpass], placeholder: 'Password', class: 'input-small'%>

        </fieldset>
        <fieldset id="actions">
            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Log in">
            <a href="/registration/register">Register</a>
        </fieldset>

        <%end%>
```

and if i submit, it sends like this,

```
Processing by LoginController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"2RQKkdOZf2HL+dsY2peWYUIaY78WBZBvNveKKBvZv60=", "something"=>{"username
"=>"test"}, "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "userpass1"=>"test2", "userpass"=>"est3"}
```

in here, the first password field is sending with filtered, but the other two are just showing what the user typed.

what is the problem?

and the most big problem is, after i send this and check the request header,

it shows all the parameter, even the data what have been filetered like this,

[image]

Any good solution about this?!

Comment: All data *always* sends like this (I mean form data). The hide feature of password_field is useful just to avoid spying by somebody behind you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have line

```
config.filter_parameters += [:password]
```

in your config/application.rb. Modify it to:

```
config.filter_parameters += [:password, :userpass, :userpass1, :userpass2]
```

That causes filtering additional parameters in logs.

The second "problem"  is not a problem at all. How do you suppose server to know what your parameters are if you want to filter them in request?

Comment: but the user can see all the parameter, especially password!. Isn't there a good solution about this?

Comment: @Canna No, there isn't. Check any web application with user authentication and you'll see the same "problem".

Comment: awell....if i login to google, it doesn't show it. Anyway, thanks for the filter problem :)